# Script doesn't save Sheets data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code that is designed to access the spreadsheet every hour and update a value, as shown below.

```js
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
var sheets = {};
function updatePlayers() {
    sheets['Users'] = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Users');
    var data = sheets['Users'].getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
        data[i][2]++;
    }
    sheets['Users'].getDataRange().setValues(data);
}
```

However, I notice that the values don't increase by 24 every day, but a varying number significantly lesser. This also occurs in other parts of my scripts where a group of information should all be updated at once, but some is renewed while others aren't, yet it doesn't throw any errors. I've tried calling `setValues()` multiple times, but that did not change anything. Also, I've noticed this problem is only occurring now, after about 7 months of this project running.

Could this be a bug in the Sheets API or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: It works for me. I used `sheets['Users']=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

Comment: This code is executed on a time trigger. There is no active sheet because the app isn't open.

Comment: I understand that .  What's your point?  I'm just saying the script works for me.

Comment: Actually the active sheet when you `openById()` is `Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];`

Comment: @VincentHarris is there a reason you have defined your sheets as a `const`? You can't later edit it with `sheets['Users'] = ...` as that would change the `sheets` object. You say `the values don't increase by 24 every day, but a varying number significantly lesser` - how much lower than expected? What is your execution log like, can you see the script run once each hour? If so, do they all run expectedly or are there errors?

Comment: The difference varies dramatically, from 30% less to 90% less. My point being that changes to the sheet are only saved part of the time.

Comment: I've had a script run on trigger for a week and I can't reproduce this. Have you got many other triggers/Sheets API calls being run in other projects? My only other suggestion is that this is a quota issue. Check out the [Apps Script quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) and check to see if you're still witihn the limits given this has only started 7 months later.

Comment: I do have a lot of executions, but I don't get any kind of notification for reaching quota. Is this because I have set failures to notify me immediately?